# Rendering custom geometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to draw a quad between four vertices in the space using three.js. I have written the following code but it doesn't work:

```
var a = { x:10,
            y:10}
var b = {x:50,
           y:50}

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( a.x, a.y, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( b.x, b.y, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( b.x, b.y - 60, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( a.x, a.y, 2 ) );
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2) );
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "0xff1100"});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```

where am I making a mistake?
By the way, to render quads, can I use Face4 or do I have to use Face3? 
Is there any good source for learning webgl features all in one place? Three.js documentation is very well organized and complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quads are no longer supported. You need to use two `Face3`s, like so:

```
var a = { x:10,
          y:10 }
var b = { x:50,
          y:50 }

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( a.x, a.y, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( b.x, a.y, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( b.x, b.y, 2 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( a.x, b.y, 2 ) );

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) ); // counter-clockwise winding order
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 3 ) );

geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Tip: set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide` so both sides of your geometry render. You can set  it back to `THREE.FrontSide` when you are sure your geometry is correct.

For advice on learning three.js and WebGL see [Learning WebGL and three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/should-i-start-learning-webgl-or-use-three-js)

three.js r.70