# Three.js: Adding and Removing Children of Rotated Objects

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm trying to simulate a rubik's cube. I wanted to choose a face at random and rotate it. So I've created 27 cube meshes and positioned them. You can see
the working (erratically) rubik's cube here
http://codepen.io/theonepa1/full/fzAli

What is the issue.

As you can see from the above link, the smaller cubes on the edges move in a random way (atleast not the way I expect it to be)

What I've done.

When trying to rotate a face , I've grouped 9 cubes belonging to the face added them as children to a new Object3D object. I then 
rotated the object3d along its axis using object3d.rotate.x (or y or z).

What I've debugged

I've made sure that the cubes I'm selecting for the second face rotation are correct. After the first face rotation is completed, I update their 
virtual positions (not actual coordinates). So for the second face rotation I've verified that the cubes are picked correctly.

What actually happens

One observation I made was that cubes' (smaller ones) axes are altered after the object3d (parent holding the 9 cubes of a face) is rotated. And also
the cubes' coordinates are not getting auto updated after the face rotation. Say for example if one of the cube has (0,0,22) as coordinates before the face 
rotation, the coordinates are same even after the rotation. However the orientation of axes of the cube is changed.

What is the best way to rotate a group of objects around a axis ? Is using Object3D correct ?
Are we supposed to remove the children from one parent before adding it to another group for the second face rotation ?

Do I've to do some kind of update on the individual cubes before adding them to second group for the second face rotation ?

I've read some posts about applyMatrixWorld , but I really could not understand what its effect was on the orientation of the axes
and the coordinates of the cube ?

Can you let me know where can I read about the concepts like applyMatrixWorld , is it some kind of common concept in a
normal 3d programming ?

Thats a really long question. Would really appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to make use of `THREE.Object3D.attach()`.

You need to begin with all your 27 cubes as a child of the `scene`.

Let pivot be an `Object3D()`.

Let `active` be an array containing the 9 cubes you want to rotate. Now make the cubes a child of the pivot:

```
pivot.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
pivot.updateMatrixWorld();

for ( var i in active ) {

    pivot.attach( active[ i ] );

}
```

Then, after the rotation, put the cubes back as children of the `scene`.

```
pivot.updateMatrixWorld();

for ( var i in active ) {

    scene.attach( active[ i ] );

}
```

three.js r.115

Comment: that worked like a charm. But my question of how do I learn these concepts still holds. Threejs does not have a proper documentation. I'm a newbie to 3d programming, although I'm comfortable in visualizing things , I do not know how to articulate in threejs. Any help for learning will be greatly appreciated. And thank you for the help.

Comment: The best answer I can give you is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/should-i-start-learning-webgl-or-use-three-js/11970687#11970687