# ThreeJS scenegraph issues

Tags: three.js, scene, rubiks-cube

I have spent the last few days working on a rubik's cube in Three JS. I am almost done with it, but am having a problem with proper nesting of groups. Basically I have all the cubies made up and when one of the center cubies on a face is clicked, all cubies on that face are added to a group and the group is rotated. The problem is when I try to readd the cubie to the scene they go back to their original location, not the new rotated one. Here is an example if the top face is clicked

```
else if(cubie.position.x == 0 && cubie.position.y == 12.5 && cubie.position.z == 0){
    for(var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
        var cubie = scene.children[i];
        if(cubie.position.y == 12.5){
            group.add(cubie);
        }
    }
    group.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,-1,0), Math.PI/2);
}
```

and here is where I try to readd the cubie back to the scene

```
for(var i = group.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    scene.add(group.children[i]);
}
scene.remove(group);
```

if I comment out both lines, then one complete rotation appears, but since the cubies are now apart of group I cant rotate them again. If I remove the first line, and leave remove(group) then obviously the row disappears, but if I leave both lines in, then the cube doesn't change at all as if when I readd the cubie to the scene it takes its original place back...I have tried everything I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I will post the entire code to pastebin if anyone needs it.
http://pastebin.com/vj6LgR0r

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects

Comment: Thank you very much! it was exactly what I needed. Is there any way to mark a comment as a correct answer so you can get some points?

Comment: You can up-vote the answer that helped you. You can also delete this question if you want, since it is very user-specific.