# Three.js - rotating grouped meshes on multiple axes

Tags: 3d, rotation, three.js

I am new to Three.js and 3D in general. I am trying to learn by building a 3D [Rubik's Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube). I am having difficulty in rotating planes of cubes.

My Rubik's Cube is as 3x3 cube of unit cubes. Any given plane of cubes may be rotated as a group. All rotations are around the centre of the plane.

My strategy is to create each individual cube mesh inside a "wrapper" `Object3D`, so each cube rotates around world `[0,0,0]`. Each wrapper contains exactly one cube. When a given plane rotation is requested, I find all of the wrappers which contain cubes that are on that plane in world coordinates and rotate by one quarter turn.

This approach works for the first rotation and some subsequent rotations, but after several rotations, cubes appear to overlap and rotate in unexpected ways.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6ks/1/) (three.js R61) shows my problem - any of the rotations work as expected in isolation, but combinations of 2 or 3 rotations causes the (to me) unexpected behaviour. How can I fix it?

I have tried a few other approaches (like building a temporary `Object3D` for each plane rotation, rotating and applying the temporary `matrixWorld` to each cube on the plane then removing the group), but they yielded similar effects.

Building the cubes:

```
var allWrappers = [];
function newCube(x, y, z) {
  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize),
      cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterials);
      cube.position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z),
      wrapper = new THREE.Object3D();

  wrapper.add(cube);
  allWrappers.push(wrapper);
  scene.add(wrapper);
}

var increment = cubeSize + spacing;
for(var i = 0; i < dimensions; i ++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < dimensions; j ++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < dimensions; k ++) {
      var x = (i - 1) * increment,
          y = (j - 1) * increment,
          z = (k - 1) * increment;
      newCube(x, y, z);
    }
  }
}
```

Plane rotation:

```
//Move all cubes with value 'v' on axis 'axis'
function move(v, axis) {
  allWrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var cubePosition = wrapper.children[0].position.clone();
    cubePosition.applyMatrix4(wrapper.matrixWorld);

    //If the current cube has the right position on this axis,
    // rotate it one quarter turn
    if(Math.abs(cubePosition[axis] - v) < 0.0001)
       wrapper.rotation[axis] += Math.PI / 2;
  });

  render();
}
```

Comment: I bet this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects/20097857#20097857. But as a separate issue, first make sure you really understand how rotations work in three.js.

Comment: Thanks. I found that just after posting. I thought I understood rotations but I extrapolated too far from simpler examples.

Comment: Fixed JSFiddle for future reference: http://jsfiddle.net/x5e4a/1/