# object as a children of multiple objects

Tags: three.js

Can an object be a child of multiple objects?

A.add( C );
B.add( C ); is valid right?

what happens if I translate B but not A ? Will C move?

*Perspective:* I have 27 cubes in a 3 X 3 matrix. All the cubes are part of the main cube_group.
I now want to move just the top 9. Can I put them in a separate group and move the group? Will that work?

It's going to be a while, before I try this out, so thought I'd ask in the meantime.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubik's cube, hm?

You question is actually similar to this: can a ball be in two different boxes at the same time? What if I would to move one box?

It's not possible (unless it's a ball in a box in a box), neither you have real need to do something like that.

Don't group them at all, just apply centered transformation on the (logical) group of nine pieces.

So, the answer are: "no, it can't" and it's not valid".

Comment: Okay, that answers it. :) Yes, i'd have to do the nine transformations separately then. Just thought it'll be neater to code, if that was doable. And, well what I'm doing is kinda similar, but its not rubik's cube :D I'd let you know when its done.  Thanks!

Comment: So. this was it :) Just in case you're interested.
[Cubik's 2048](http://kshitij-banerjee.github.io/Cubiks-2048)

See what happens when you press the space-bar :D