# Delete an object from scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to delete an object from scene in three.js?
I want to delete a cube after certain key press.But I could not delete a particular cube but able to clear the whole scene

Comment: `cube.parent.removeChild(cube)` or https://stackoverflow.com/a/23393064/4187058

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the mesh object from the scene in the following manner.

```
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(cubeMesh);
//...

someDeleteFunction() {
    scene.remove(cubeMesh);
    cubeMesh.geometry.dispose();
    cubeMesh.material.dispose();
    cubeMesh = undefined; //clear any reference for it to be able to garbage collected
}
```

Comment: If value in range is decreamented , the cube should be deleted.Then,where to include the code given above

Comment: What do you mean by value of range? You can call the `someDeleteFunction` whenever you wish to delete the object in a callback or event listener for some action. @S.Shenbegavalli