# How can I share a mesh across several groups?

Tags: three.js

I have 27 cubes (made of C0, C1, ..., C26) in my scene, but I would like to get a group with all of them (named GAll), and two other groups : G1(made of C0, C3, C6, C9, C12, C15, C18, C21, C24) and G2(made of C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8). Indeed, all these groups needs different rotation operations.

The problem is that I can only add a mesh to only one parent at the same time. Is there a way, for example, to :

- add C0 to the scene
- add C0 to the whole cube group
- add C0 to the group G1
- add C0 to the group G2

going against the "One parent only per child" ?

Why ? Because I am trying to build a Rubik's Cube, so that changed made by a group affects all of its meshes for other groups.

Indeed, if I try to add a child to several groups, only the last "added group" will be retained.

I am using Three.js revision 68.

Comment: You can always clone a mesh.

Comment: Thank you, but cloning is not good for my application (a Rubik's Cube) : I really need different groups for same meshes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects/20097857#20097857