# How can I rotate an object based on its position with WebGL (and THREE.js library)?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm doing a Rubik's cube in WebGL. I created 27 little cubes That form a big one, but I do not know how to say "rotate the cubes that are in that particular position (the block of 9 on the top for example)".
The cubes always change their position so I need a dinamic way to call them. 
How can I do it? How can I call a group of cubes and rotate them not by their names but thanks their position?

In my code I have only created the cubes and I have added them to the scene to create the big one, not more.

I really need help, so thx a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects.

Answer (score -1):

I've been following and contributing to a project that lets you create WebGL based apps very easily. It's called whitestormJS and you can check it out [here](https://whsjs.io/#/)

So whitestorm is just simply a wrapper for Three.js tt has a nice API and it will simplify many things. Anyways despite of what you're using. I would suggest you to use groups to move all the faces. Jonathan Petitcolas has a nice [tutorial](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/04/02/create-rotating-cube-in-webgl-with-threejs.html) about rotation in Three.js.

```
//you should create a group for each face with its proper cubes
var face1 = new THREE.Group();
group.add(piece1);
group.add(piece2);
// and so on, finally set a rotation to the group on the proper axis.
pivot.rotation.y = 1.5708; //this is 90 degrees in radians
```

Comment: but if i use this kind of method, I use the names of the cubes... when they change the position they are mixed with other cubes and the effect is completely a mess