# How to rotate Object3d around X,Y & Z axis without having the axes to flip or cause gimbal lock?

Tags: three.js, rotation, quaternions

Probably threejs's rotation question no 9000 , i simply want to have 3 UI buttons to incrementally rotate an object 90 degrees in either x,y & z direction with every click on each, how hard could it be ?

Using regular rotation methods which uses euler will cause gimbal lock, and using quanternions the axes will flip randomly in which z-axis will be y-axis at one point or another.

please have a look at my working demo :  http://grutex.com/webgl/demos/help/

Edit: here is the rotation functions part :

```
        function z_rotate(){

        var startAngle = 0;
        var start = {angle: startAngle};
        var end = {angle: startAngle + 90};
        var lastAngle=0;                                
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
          .to(end, 400)
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out )
          .onUpdate(function(){
              startAngle=this.angle;    
              my_object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1),degreeToRadians(startAngle-lastAngle));
              lastAngle=startAngle;                     
           })
          .start(); 


    }

    function x_rotate(){

        var startAngle = 0;
        var start = {angle: startAngle};
        var end = {angle: startAngle + 90};
        var lastAngle=0;                                
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
          .to(end, 400)
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out )
          .onUpdate(function(){
              startAngle=this.angle;
              my_object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0),degreeToRadians(startAngle-lastAngle));
              lastAngle=startAngle;                     
           })
          .start();
    }

    function y_rotate(){
        var startAngle = 0;
        var start = {angle: startAngle};
        var end = {angle: startAngle + 90};
        var lastAngle=0;                                
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
          .to(end, 400)
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out )
          .onUpdate(function(){
              startAngle=this.angle;
              my_object.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),degreeToRadians(startAngle-lastAngle));
              lastAngle=startAngle;                     
           })
          .start();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add you code to your post. Tip: avoid calling `new` every frame. Create one instance of an object and reuse it.

Comment: Study [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects/20097857#20097857), and tween the rotation of a temporary parent object, instead.

Comment: @WestLangley thank you!, if it weren't for you i would've been banging my head to the wall for days on end, you're the only person i wished for to answer me after reading a ton of your answers on SO regarding three.js, i'll post the tweaked code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WestLangley pointed out, i should attach and detach the 3d object to a parent pivot point (THREE.Object3D), attaching the 3d object to the pivot point before the tween start and detaching the pivot point after tween completion and resetting its rotation to (0,0,0)

@WestLangley answer : [Three.js: Adding and Removing Children of Rotated Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects/20097857#20097857)

New modified rotation function :

```
var axis_x = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ).normalize();

    function x_rotate(){
        pivot_attach();
        var startAngle = 0;
        var start = {angle: degreeToRadians(startAngle)};
        var end = {angle: degreeToRadians(startAngle + 90)};
        var lastAngle=0;                                
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
          .to(end, 400)
          .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out )
          .onUpdate(function(){
              startAngle=this.angle;
             pivot.rotateOnAxis(axis_x,startAngle-lastAngle);
              lastAngle=startAngle;                     
           })
          .start().onComplete(pivot_detach);
    }

function pivot_attach() {

    pivot.updateMatrixWorld();
    THREE.SceneUtils.attach( my_object, scene, pivot );

}

function pivot_detach() {

    pivot.updateMatrixWorld();
    my_object.updateMatrixWorld(); // if not done by the renderer

    THREE.SceneUtils.detach( my_object, pivot, scene );
    pivot.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );

}
```

and don't forget to add the pivot to the scene "scene.add(pivot);"

Comment: Specify your angles in radians to begin with.

Comment: they are hence the "degreeToRadians()"  function, or i could use "THREE.Math.degToRad( degrees );" method.

Comment: Your angles are in degrees. `angle: startAngle + 90`

Comment: oh right right, you mean changing it outside the update loop, fixed it that should save some processing cycles, i should probably get some sleep haha