# THREE.JS Multiple groups containing the same objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm currently learning THREE.js and trying to make a playable rubik's cube.

I want to be able to rotate a face as a whole instead of moving every single cube one at a time, and I can do so by creating a THREE.Group and adding the cubes in it. The problem is that a single cube is contained in multiple faces, and I can't find a solution. If I create an object, add it to a first group, then add it to a second group, it is removed from the first group.

I'm pretty sure there is a workaround but can't find it as I'm really new to THREE.js and 3D programming (I only followed a basic course https://www.udemy.com/3d-programming-with-javascript-and-the-threejs-3d-library/).

There is my code but I don't think it will be very usefull anyway.

https://pastebin.com/Hq66UvBU

```
Thanks
```

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089098/three-js-adding-and-removing-children-of-rotated-objects

Comment: I already found this but can't get it to work, plus it's pretty old :/

Comment: I think `THREE.Group` is the wrong class for your use case. As you said, a single cube needs to be organized in such a way that it's possible to implement multiple memberships to different sides of the rubik's cube. I suggest to use a custom data structure and transform the single cubes in a special way when the users perform a change. BTW: Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/15227/) with your code.

Comment: Also interesting: https://github.com/joews/rubik-js

Comment: I'll see what I can do with that, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to edit your question to include your code, because when the pastebin link dies, your question loses important context.

The correct way to add an object to a `THREE.Group` is through [the `add` function](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add), like you do. But an object added to multiple groups will only ever be a child of *the last* group to which it was added. This is because `add` looks to see if the object already has a defined `parent`, and removes the object from that parent before setting the new parent ([r97 code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2410ad1a8f5844df00191600eafda59def537830/src/core/Object3D.js#L378)).

Example:

```
let obj = new THREE.Object3D()
let p1 = new THREE.Group()
let p2 = new THREE.Group()

p1.add(obj) // obj.parent == p1
p2.add(obj) // 1. three.js calls p1.remove(obj) 2. obj.parent == p2
```

Beyond this reason, and as @Mugen87 mentioned, your cubes need to not only be able to have multiple memberships, but also to be able to enter and leave face groups as their positions change. To me this says you will almost *need* to transform the cubes individually. You could use a `THREE.Group` to make it easier to conceptualize, but there would be extra overhead to actually implement it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer but try to work in another way and group the cubes that need to turn the moment the turn function is activated and then turn the group around, then empty the group.