# How to merge vertices

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js

I'm basically new to Three.js I find Three.js intersting because I can animate 3D without using any Flash or whatever.

But my problem is that **I don't know how to merge 2 simple triangles as one.**

So here's my code:

```
<body>

<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>

 var camera, scene, renderer;
 var geometry, geometry1, material, mesh;
 var FrontSide, Backside;
  init();
  animate();

function init() {
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000);   
    camera.position.z = 1000;
scene = new THREE.Scene();

geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, 100 ) ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, 100 ) ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3(  100, 100, 100 ) ) );

geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

geometry1 = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry1.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3( -100,  100, 100 ) ) );
geometry1.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3( -100, -100, 100 ) ) );
geometry1.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex ( new THREE.Vector3(  100, 100, 100 ) ) );

geometry1.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
color: 0x00ff00,
wireFrame: true,
wireFrameLinewidth: 3
});

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    }

function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        //mesh.rotation.x += 0.01; 
        //mesh.rotation.y -= 0.04;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is compatible with a version of the three.js library that is 2 years old. Update to the current version. Study the current three.js examples -- not old examples from the net or outdated books. Use `geometry.merge( geometry1 );`

Comment: Can you direct me to those books? So I can learn something from it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js/11970687#11970687, http://threejs.org/examples, and, although currently a bit out-of-date, http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/.