# Animating planet orbiting it's parent idependent on parent's rotation state

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, matrix-transform

I'm trying to learn Three.js, beeing new to those technologies. I achieved a sun with planet orbitting around, with moon orbitting around planet. What am I concerned of, is to do what i have so far i have to make quite a lot of objects and perform quite a lot of calculations during rendering loops.

## 1. Sourcecodes:

[WestLangley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461008/westlangley) provided us with fiddles presenting problem in more easy-to-understand way so:

- [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t83pzoj2/) presents more like it is looking right now - planet has its parent inside sun, and rotating that parent will make planet orbit. But along with one extra object per planet/moon, theres an issue that parent rotation spins planet in place too, during to `updateMatrixWorld` Object3D method. So it will spin a bit faster than you may assume by looking at `mesh2.rotateOnAxis( AXIS, 0.01 );` bit.
- [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t83pzoj2/4/) shows one parent-less approach. Case is, I'm trying to find way, where I can configure planet positions/spins-speed/orbit-speed at system start and than just feed it with server time, so it will make it feel synchronised between players being at same location.

## 3. Question itself

As far as I travelled through manuals, I found there may be a possibility of performing such animation using Three.js matrix logic. I'm willing to reduce usage of `::animate()` inside objects as far as possible (maybe by overriding `updateMatrix` and `updateMatrixWorld` methods). Unfortunately my english nor math are not good enough to understand, whats going around with those matrixes. If somebody can help me, I would really appreciate this.

## 4. Current work progress

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e2dfwt48/9/). I was able to create a Planet and have almost all I want. One left issue is that, a would like to planet orbit at more random-looking degrees.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t83pzoj2/) shows how three.js is intended to be used. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js/11970687#11970687) for some math resources.

Comment: @WestLangley this looks exactly like what I have right now. Problem is, that rotation of pivot along changing mesh2 position, changes its local rotation in result of `updateWorldMatrix` I am willing in controlling its rotation speed separately and avoid using empty Object3D elements as parents. Is it at least possible?

Comment: Is this what you mean -- with no pivots? http://jsfiddle.net/t83pzoj2/4/

Comment: @WestLangley looks like it work the way I'm willing to achieve, but i wonder about spinning moon around planet at certain position with this approach. If you are able to manage it simply I may accept that as answer :)

Comment: It has only been 15 minutes. I expect you can figure it out yourself and answer your own question. : - )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forked this bit around. I was willing to reduce object count in my solar system, hide calculations from animation loop nad make it as configurable as possible.

To make this I implemented custom `Mesh` called `Planet`:

```
var Planet =  function ( geometry, material ) {
    THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );
    this.type = 'Planet';
};
Planet.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
```

and overriden standard `Object3D` matrix-calculation functions:

```
Planet.prototype._matrixUpdate = THREE.Object3D.prototype.updateMatrix;
Planet.prototype._updateMatrixWorld = THREE.Object3D.prototype.updateMatrixWorld;
Planet.prototype.updateMatrix = function() {};
Planet.prototype.updateMatrixWorld = function() {};
```

Thanks to that I can recalculate positions and rotations of planets/moons created on that base inside standard methods been running every render call.

For good start I've prototyped in Planet constructor some basic arguments I will need:

```
    this.rotationAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ).normalize(); // always rotate on Y
    this.rotationSpeed = Math.PI/2; // length of planet day

    this.orbitAxis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0.1, 1 ).normalize(); // y,z for orbit AXIS
    this.orbitSpeed = Math.PI / 8; // length of planet year
```

those should be configurable on creation time, but for now hardcode is ok.

Than going into new `updateMatrix()`, to calculate current planet position in relation of it's parent:

```
Planet.prototype.updateMatrix = function() {

    var dta = delta || 0; // THREE.Clock::getDelta

    // just for now, sun is not orbiting around
    // anything, so checking instance
    if ( this.parent instanceof Planet ) {
        // rotate position in relation to parent, to make planet orbit
        this.position.applyAxisAngle(this.orbitAxis, this.orbitSpeed * dta);
    }

    // rotate planet in place, to make it spin
    this.rotateOnAxis(this.rotationAxis, this.rotationSpeed * dta);

    this._matrixUpdate(); // fabricating Object3D.matrix
};
```

And last, but not least - providing those changes to `Object3D.worldMatrix` via `updateMatrixWorld` implementation:

```
Planet.prototype.updateMatrixWorld = function() {
    if ( this.matrixAutoUpdate === true ) this.updateMatrix();

    if ( this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate === true || force === true ) {

        if ( this.parent === undefined ) {
            this.matrixWorld.copy( this.matrix );
        } else {
            // THIS else block is all whats different
            // between Planet and standard Object3Dmethod
            v = new THREE.Vector3(); // empty vector
            v.applyMatrix4(this.parent.matrixWorld); // setup with parent position
            v.add(this.position); // add local position

            // compose instead of multiplication
            this.matrixWorld.compose(v, this.quaternion, this.scale); 

        }
   // ... rest like in THREE's (71) git.
```

Working code is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2dfwt48/12/). This way I have reduced math-time during render loop, reduced nested code and finally: reduced objects count by up to 50%. But I'm am not 100% confident about that answer, so any further optimisations are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Helped a lot.