# Lost in THREEJS

Tags: three.js, webgl

My goal is to go over these since they are a bit more challenging: http://threejs.org/examples/

However, I've found these very hard to understand. For instance, the source code from lines 120-247 in the following example are completely lost on me: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry

Do I have to learn WebGL and GLSL in order to comprehend what is going on? If so, what is the best way to tackle the situation and absorb the knowledge?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js/11970687#11970687

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning WebGL and three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js)

Answer (score 1):

There's already an question asking for learning resources for WebGL, but since this one is specifically tied to THREE.js I would like to share this free [course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/interactive-3d-graphics--cs291).

IMHO the basic concepts of 3D graphics are more important than getting directly into the code, and this course excels in explaining it and applying those explanations using THREE.js.

It's sponsored by Autodesk so you should expect some self-promotion here and there, but the lessons are relatively short. If you're a beginner both in 3D graphics and THREE.js I think it will worth it.