# 3D interactive map using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want learn three.js but i don't know where to start. I don't have knowledge about it but i really want to study and learn. I'm planning to develop an interactive 3D map using three.js. Please help me and give some advices.

Comment: welcome to SO.  it is best to find "howto" docs and tutorials from the library creators and user community and to come back here with more specific programming questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Despite of what many people think, StackOverflow is probably the worst place for newbies to learn. It is mainly for specific questions (and some occasional interesting-but-dumb-questions that are equally upvoted ;-). Take a look at this tutorial: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-noobs-guide-to-threejs--cms-28639 (sorry about the tutorial name) don't doubt in asking a more specific question. Best wishes in your learning process!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966779/learning-webgl-and-three-js/11970687#11970687) are some suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

Three.js is a JavaScript library which means it will be best to start learning JavaScript first. A great start will be W3schools.com which is made by a Norwegian software development and consulting company to educate people interesting in programming with the standard of programming. On W3schools.com they have a JavaScript course which teaches the fundamental of JavaScript like how to use the DOM, make interactive website, and other fundamental concepts. After learning the fundamental of JavaScript I would go on Three JS website and learn their documentation which is https://threejs.org/ and click on documentation.

Comment: Most programmers prefer the MDN, primarily due to the fact that W3Schools used to (and occasionally still does) have outdated information and used a number of depricated features (namely document.write) in its tutorials.

Comment: Even though W3Schools uses some deprecated features it offers a more comprehensive overview of JavaScript and include JavaScript libraries like JQuery and framework like Angular.

Comment: The MDN is far more comprehensive, but W3Schools may be better for beginners to just start off with. The MDN (this isn’t my analogy, it’s from a an excellent Meta thread on the subject) is like a fire hose, it contains all of the info you want, and more. W3Schools is like a condensed, albeit somewhat inaccurate (on occasion) “digest copy”.  The jQuery and Angular tutorials are fine, but I have found (via Google Search) that there are other places with just as good (if not better) tutorials on the subject.

Comment: By no means is the following true: `W3schools.com which is made by an organization that manage the Internet.`

Comment: Your Right W3schools.com I just found out is not affiliated with W3C with fix post.